# Insert array and non array values to database using a single sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this, working, code, for inserting array to database:

```
$c = array_map(function ($reqNo,$officer,$product,$quantity){return "'$reqNo','$officer','$product','$quantity'";} , $reqNo,$officer,$product,$quantity);

if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO request (RNO,UID,PID,QtyR) VALUES (".implode('),(', $c).")"))
```

Now, the problems is that i would like also to insert, alongside the array, none array values to the same database table, using the same sql insert statement..here's my code so far,

```
if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO request (RNO,UID,PID,QtyR,Iuse,Designation,QtyA,QtyA1,QtyI,Rdate,Rtime,bar) VALUES (".implode('),(', $c).",'replacement','ICTU','-1','-1','-1',CURDATE(),CURTIME(),'1' )"))
```

and here's the error i'm getting:

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Read the error. It tells you all you need to know. Hint, put the query into a string and dump it. The issue should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I did get a way around it, though not sure if it's the correct way..this' how i did it:

```
//first, i got the length of the array
for($i=0;$i<count($product);$i++){}

//i used array_fill() to duplicate the single values into the length of the array
$new_usage = array_fill(0,$i,$usage);
$new_designation = array_fill(0,$i,$designation);
$QtyA = array_fill(0,$i,"-1");
$QtyA1 = array_fill(0,$i,"-1");
$QtyI = array_fill(0,$i,"-1");
$date = array_fill(0,$i,date("Y-m-d"));
$time = array_fill(0,$i,date("H:i:s"));
$bar = array_fill(0,$i,"1");

//then i put the above new arrays into array_map(), together with the original array
$c = array_map(function ($reqNo,$officer,$product,$quantity,$new_usage,$new_designation,$QtyA,$QtyA1,$QtyI,$date,$time,$bar){return "'$reqNo','$officer','$product','$quantity','$new_usage','$new_designation','$QtyA','$QtyA1','$QtyI','$date','$time','$bar'";} , $reqNo,$officer,$product,$quantity,$new_usage,$new_designation,$QtyA,$QtyA1,$QtyI,$date,$time,$bar);

//from there, i imploded the array_map into the sql insert statement
if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO request (RNO,UID,PID,QtyR,Iuse,Designation,QtyA,QtyA1,QtyI,Rdate,Rtime,bar) VALUES (".implode('),(', $c).")")){
...
```

I still don't know if this' the right way to go about it, but all in all, it did work.